# Error compiling structmember.h from Python2.7 library

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, g++

I'm trying to create a Cmake file to compile an old C++ proyect, but when I run the make command I have this compile error:

```
In file included from /home/leontes/Dropbox/Siadex_Planner_ROS/planner/src/pyAPI.cpp:23:0:
/usr/include/python2.7/structmember.h:40:5: error: ‘Py_ssize_t’ does not name a type
     Py_ssize_t offset;
     ^

/usr/include/python2.7/structmember.h:88:24: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘PyMember_Get’
 PyAPI_FUNC(PyObject *) PyMember_Get(const char *, struct memberlist *, const char *);
                        ^

/usr/include/python2.7/structmember.h:89:17: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘PyMember_Set’
 PyAPI_FUNC(int) PyMember_Set(char *, struct memberlist *, const char *, PyObject *);
                 ^

/usr/include/python2.7/structmember.h:92:24: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘PyMember_GetOne’
 PyAPI_FUNC(PyObject *) PyMember_GetOne(const char *, struct PyMemberDef *);
                        ^

/usr/include/python2.7/structmember.h:93:17: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘PyMember_SetOne’
 PyAPI_FUNC(int) PyMember_SetOne(char *, struct PyMemberDef *, PyObject *);
                 ^

make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/planner.dir/src/pyAPI.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/planner.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

And that is a System Library from Python...

I fixed the old make what was included with the proyect and it works fine, but with the new one no.

And the Cmakelist.txt that I'm building is this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(planner)

#Set headers directory
include_directories(include ${PYTHON_INCLUDE_PATH})

#Set source files
file(GLOB SOURCES "src/*.cpp")

#Set python vars
#Compiler flags
execute_process(COMMAND python-config --cflags OUTPUT_VARIABLE PYTHON_CPPFLAGS OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE) 

#Libraries
execute_process(COMMAND python-config --libs OUTPUT_VARIABLE PYTHON_EXTRA_LIBS OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)

#Linker flags
execute_process(COMMAND python-config --ldflags OUTPUT_VARIABLE PYTHON_LDFLAGS OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)


#Concatenate the new flags with the old ones
    set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS ${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} ${PYTHON_CPPFLAGS})
    set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS ${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} ${PYTHON_LDFLAGS})

#Define preprocessor directives for debugger.cpp
if(EXISTS /usr/include/readline.h)
  add_definitions(-DHAVE_LIBREADLINE)
  add_definitions(-DHAVE_READLINE_H)
endif(EXISTS /usr/include/readline.h)
if(EXISTS /usr/include/readline/readline.h)
  add_definitions(-DHAVE_LIBREADLINE)
  add_definitions(-DHAVE_READLINE_READLINE_H)
endif(EXISTS /usr/include/readline/readline.h)
if(EXISTS /usr/include/history.h)
  add_definitions(-DHAVE_READLINE_HISTORY)
  add_definitions(-DHAVE_HISTORY_H)
endif(EXISTS /usr/include/history.h)
if(EXISTS /usr/include/readline/history.h)
  add_definitions(-DHAVE_READLINE_HISTORY)
  add_definitions(-DHAVE_READLINE_HISTORY_H)
endif(EXISTS /usr/include/readline/history.h)

#Define preprocessor directives for stacknode.cpp
add_definitions(-DUSE_AC3)
#add_definitions(-DUSE_PC2)
#add_definitions(-DUSE_PC2_CL)




#Add a binary executable
add_executable(planner nodes/planner.cpp ${SOURCES})
#And link it
target_link_libraries(planner python2.7 readline ${PYTHON_EXTRA_LIBS})
```

I'm missing something??

EDIT:

Command used to compile in the old 'make'

```
g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../..   -Wall -Iheaders  -I../xmlrpc/headers -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/python2.7  -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes  -DPYTHON_FOUND -DWITH_XMLRPC -g -O2 -DBUFFER_STACK -MT sources/pyAPI.o -MD -MP -MF $depbase.Tpo -c -o sources/pyAPI.o sources/pyAPI.cpp &&\
```

Command used to compile in the new 'make'

```
/usr/bin/c++   -DHAVE_LIBREADLINE -DHAVE_READLINE_HISTORY -DHAVE_READLINE_HISTORY_H -DHAVE_READLINE_READLINE_H -DUSE_PC2_CL -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/python2.7  -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/home/leontes/Dropbox/Siadex_Planner_ROS/planner/include -I/usr/include/python2.7    -o CMakeFiles/planner.dir/src/pyAPI.cpp.o -c /home/leontes/Dropbox/Siadex_Planner_ROS/planner/src/pyAPI.cpp
```

Comment: Check which compiler is used by `make` and `CMake`. Probably one, used by `CMake`, has been installed incorrectly (while `make` uses correctly installed compiler).

Comment: The compiler used by make and Cmake is GNU g++ version 4.8.2

Comment: Hm, so the next step could be comparing precise command lines, used for compile executable, in old way(with `make` only) and in new way(with `make` executed for files, generated by `CMake`). In the last case(when CMake is used) using `make V=1` will output precise command lines executed within build process.

Comment: There is the commad line  `/usr/bin/c++   -DHAVE_LIBREADLINE -DHAVE_READLINE_HISTORY -DHAVE_READLINE_HISTORY_H -DHAVE_READLINE_READLINE_H -DUSE_PC2_CL  -I/home/leontes/Dropbox/Siadex_Planner_ROS/planner/include -I/usr/include/python2.7    -o CMakeFiles/planner.dir/src/pyAPI.cpp.o -c /home/leontes/Dropbox/Siadex_Planner_ROS/planner/src/pyAPI.cpp` I've tried to compile the program in another computer and It gives me the same errors... but in a different include.

Comment: And what command line is with old make, when everything works?

Comment: Added to the questions the commands for both makefiles. And fixed the CMake, It didn't include the python-config -cflags to the CXXFLAGS

Comment: Edit. I fixed the error. It was a missing preprocessor definition.